# Icon vs Text Editing Table

Tags: icons, tables, hyperlinks, edit

In the context of a table in which each row represents a user, what is better to use? An edit icon at the end of each row, or the Edit text underlined as a hyperlink?

Comment: I think we would need to know more about the rest of the visual language for your product and the context of this table to answer with anything more than just opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If space allows, try providing both icon and label. Icons alone are famous to have non-universal comprehension (except those that have being around for decades). Even the hamburger icon is notorious to be confusing to users.

If providing icons alone, labels alone or both on each row becomes too repetitive down the rows, maybe you should consider some other approaches such as:

1. Highlighting each cell when hovered, or some other visual indication that allows the user to click and directly edit the cell like in excel.
2. Allowing the user to click into the row, and on the user detail page, allow users to simply click on an attribute value (e.g. Last name) and edit it. This automatically activates the edit state, providing a save button.

Answer (score 0):

An Edit icon - because they are universal and cross language. To avoid crowding or repetition, you could show the icon only upon hover.

Comment: But if you show it only upon hover, how would users know that they can actually edit something? They have to move around a little to figure out that there is a hover option.